# Add images to corresponding messages to my discord bot using python

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, embed

I made a small bot for my discord sever for fun and I am trying to see if I can add corresponding images to a list of messages my bot sends in the channel after I type the command in. I tried looking for tutorials online, but I couldn't find what I am looking for.

This is my code for to send the messages after triggering the command:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import os

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="=",intents=discord.Intents.all())`

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

all_tips = ["message","message","message","message","message","message"]
not_shown = all_tips[:]

@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role("Boss","Test")
async def tip(ctx): 
    global not_shown
    if len(not_shown) == 0:
        not_shown = all_tips[:]
    tips = random.choice(not_shown)
    not_shown.remove(tips)
    embed = discord.Embed(colour = discord.Colour.green())
    embed.set_author(name=tips)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await ctx.message.delete()
@tip.error
async def tip_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingAnyRole):
        embed = discord.Embed(colour = discord.Colour.red())
        embed.set_author(name="You can't use that!!!")
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

client.run(os.getenv("token"))
```

Now I could get the image link next to my message, like this:

```
all_tips = ["message https://image.png","message https://image.png","message https://image.png","message https://image.png","message https://image.png","message https://image.png"]
```

and discord will show me the image when the bot posts the message, but it doesn't look good. Also if add the embed part when the message is sent, I only see the link of the image. So I would like to know if there is a way to do this in an embed message.

Comment: try using `embed.set_image(url)`? [Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=set_image#discord.Embed.set_image)